# Convert each string in a list into a list of strings

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I have two functions, one is

```
let make_row delim str = List.map String.trim (Str.split (Str.regexp delim) str)
```

and the other is

```
let rec table_of_stringlist delim rlist = match rlist with
| h::[]-> make_row delim h
| h::t -> table_of_stringlist delim (make_row delim h)::t)
```

but the second one is giving me trouble. I am trying to make it so essentially `table_of_stringlist d [r1;r2;...;rN]` should evaluate to `[(make_row d r1); (make_row d r2); ...; (make_row d rN)]`. The value d is a delimiter so for example `table_of_stringlist "|" ["a|b|c"; "d|e"]`
should evaluate to
`[["a";"b";"c"]; ["d";"e"]]`. I am confused on how to write my match cases in the second function. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to pass the new list (the table) along your recursive function as you build it, returning that new list once you reach the end of `rlist`

```ml
let rec table_of_stringlist delim rlist table = match rlist with
| [] -> table
| h::t->
    let new_row = make_row delim h in
    table_of_stringlist delim t (table @ [new_row])
```

When you call it the first time, pass in an empty list as the `table`.

> Note: I haven't actually tested the snipped above so it may not be syntactically correct, but it should be close to what you need.

Comment: What would be a good way of doing it without implementing table? So I just convert the strings in rlist into a list of strings

Comment: Yeah, that's what this is doing, the table is just a list of list of strings in this case, I just named it `table` you could call it whatever you want

Comment: depending on the size of rlist this might be inefficient to concatenate on the right of a list

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to rearrange your first function a little bit for readability.

```
let make_row delim str = 
  let delim = Str.regexp delim in
  str 
  |> Str.split delim
  |> List.map String.trim
```

Now, let's give your second function some attention. Aside from some syntactic changes, you had an extraneous paren at the end. If we remove that, we see:

```
let rec table_of_stringlist delim rlist = 
  match rlist with
  | [h] -> make_row delim h
  | h::t -> table_of_stringlist delim (make_row delim h) :: t
```

Problems:

This doesn't handle the case where `rlist` is empty.

The function is not recursively being called on the tail of the list, but rather on the results of making a "row" out of the first string. This prompts a type error.

```
utop # let rec table_of_stringlist delim rlist =
  match rlist with
  | [h] -> make_row delim h
  | h::t -> table_of_stringlist delim (make_row delim h) :: t;;
Error: This expression has type string list
       but an expression was expected of type string
```

Because `t` has type `string list` anything prepended onto it with `::` must be a string, but `make_row` returns a `string list`.

We can address the first concern by having your function return an empty list when `rlist` is empty. The second concern we address by applying `make_row` to the first element, and recursively calling `table_of_stringlist` on the tail, consing the two together with `::`.

```
let rec table_of_stringlist delim rlist =
  match rlist with
  | [] -> []
  | h::t -> (make_row delim h) :: table_of_stringlist delim t
```

```
utop # table_of_stringlist "|" ["a|b|c"; "d|e"];;
- : string list list = [["a"; "b"; "c"]; ["d"; "e"]]
```

Of course, this is really just `List.map`.

```
let table_of_stringlist delim rlist = 
  List.map (fun x -> make_row delim x) rlist
```

Or more tersely:

```
let table_of_stringlist delim = List.map (make_row delim)
```